# Ошибка 15 Access denied: wall is disabled | vk_api

Tags: vkontakte-api

Раньше все было нормально и этой ошибки не было, теперь она появляется каждый раз при попытке комментировании поста в VK.
В коде ничего не менял, в чем может быть проблема?

1. Аккаунт может оставлять посты вручную
2. Прокси рабочие

Видимо не работают прокси хотя при авторизации указано:

```
def auth_bot():
    login_data = get_saved_login_data()
    s = requests.Session()
    try:
        active_proxy = get_active_proxy_for_vk()
        if active_proxy:
            proxy_id, proxy_data = active_proxy
            proxy_url, proxy_port, username, password = proxy_data.split(':')

            s.proxies.update({
                'http': f'http://{username}:{password}@{proxy_url}:{proxy_port}'
            })

            try:
                ip_check_response = s.get('http://ipinfo.io/ip')
                ip_check_response.raise_for_status()
                current_ip = ip_check_response.text.strip()
                print(current_ip)
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                error_message = f"❌ Ошибка при подключении к прокси: {e}"
                send_auth_error_to_telegram(error_message)
                return False

        else:
            send_auth_error_to_telegram("⚠️ У вас нет прокси, либо вы не выбрали рабочие. Используется прямое соединение, шанс бана повышен!")
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"❌ Неизвестная ошибка: {str(e)}"
        send_auth_error_to_telegram(error_message)
        return False

    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login_data[1],
                              login_data[2],
                              session=s,
                              app_id=2685278)

    try:
        vk_session.http.headers[
                'User-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0'
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
        vk = vk_session.get_api()
        run_bot(vk, s)
        return vk_session
```

Код для работы:

```
def run_bot(vk, session):
    print('-1')
    last_timestamp = int(time.time())
    min_sleep, max_sleep = get_sleep_settings()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            for group_id in get_active_groups_vk_bot():
                group_name = vk.groups.getById(group_id=abs(group_id))[0]['name']
                print('0')
                posts = vk.wall.get(owner_id=group_id, count=10, offset=0, filter='all', latest=1, fields='post_type')['items']
                time.sleep(4)
                for post in posts:
                    if post['date'] > last_timestamp:
                        post_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(post['date']).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                        post_string = post['text']
                        reply = generate_reply(post_string)
                        good_reply = reply.replace('?', '')
                        for comment_text in good_reply:
                            if post['date'] > last_timestamp:
                                response = vk.wall.createComment(owner_id=group_id, post_id=post['id'], message=good_reply, session=session)
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так если прокси подключил!